# Azure .NET5 MVC6 WebApi basic app is very slow

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I've recently started developing .NET applications (particularly with the new .NET 5) and I've came across a strange problem. When I created a template WebApi application (Project -> New -> ... -> ASP.NET 5 WebApi Application) and measured its performance, it turned out that its just tragic.

This is the controller that I was querying :

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

I ran it under Release, 1.0.0-rc1-update runtine and for benchmarking I used ApacheBench with a following command:

```
ab -n 500 -c 10 http://localhost:62066/api/values
```

Which is 500 requests with a concurrency equal to 10. 
And the server was able to return astonishing... 39 requests per second! When I publish such application to Azure, performance is similar, but maximum CPU usage registered was about 15% and memory consumption stopped at about 50%. Application tier is S1 (Standard 1, 1 core, 1.75GB RAM).

I've also created super simple NodeJS server locally :

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.port || 1337;
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(port);
```

With the same ApacheBench setting, performance was about 1500 requests/sec which is very fast compared to MVC6. Unfortunately, after publishing NodeJS to Azure, application performance dropped significantly to about 40 requests per second, again with CPU utilization not exceeding 15% and memory at about 50%.

Are there some options blocking full performance of such application? Have I forgotten about some settings?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you hit the outgoing connection limit rather than the incoming limit. What client OS?

Comment: You mean the operating system that I'm running the tests from? Everything is done from Win10.

Comment: Yes, the system that sends requests. It doesn't look like a coincidence that everytime you send requests to a remote cloud, you get around 40 req/s.

Comment: I mentioned that NodeJS was able to deliver 1500 requests/sec on the same machine, so shouldn't it be also affected by the OS?

Comment: Seems like local connections are not capped. The limit is there since Windows xp and you can easily find information on how to raise it for Windows 7. I am not posting this as an answer only because I have no idea if W7 workaround works on W10.

Comment: Yeah, but those 39 requests came from local test also. Server was run from VisualStudio.

Comment: Just find the common workaround, repeat the test and come back with results.

Comment: Did you deploy your NodeJs App to an Azure Website or a Virtual Machine ?

Comment: I deployed it to Azure Website, with the same specs mentioned above (Standard S1).